# Troubleshooting Mirroring Configuration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, mirroring

I am configuring database mirroring on SQL Server 2012.  After configuration I am getting the following error when attempting to start the mirroring session:

> tcp server cannot be reached or does not exist.  Check the network address name and the ports for the local and remote are operational.
>
> an Exception occured while executing a Transactional-SQL Statment.

Comment: Are you using FQDN - fully qualified domain name ? Also, are the end points configured properly? Try the steps mentioned at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/01/11/the-server-network-address-tcpsqlserver5023-can-not-be-reached-or-does-not-exist-check-the-network-address-name-and-that-the-ports-for-the-local-and-remote-endpoints-are-operational-microso/

Comment: yes am using FQDN and End points are configured properly.

Comment: For your info am not able to use Telnet from my servers

Comment: is it giving u error ?

Comment: Gives me that Telnet is not recognized as internatl or external command,operable program or batch file

Comment: Telnet Client might not be installed in your Windows features.  As long as you can connect from both machines to each other, its fine. The error youbposted is more generic,  can you check the error log as well ?

Comment: I am able to solve the issue for configuration but now facing issues for auto failure,after configuring mirror with witness server when primary server is done Mirroring(Secondar) server is not coming online and if i try to execute some select statment in Query window it stats the below Error:Database Test_Mirror is enabled for Database Mirroring, but the database lacks quorum: the database cannot be opened.  Check the partner and witness connections if configured.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10522/discussion-between-user2315732-and-kin)

Answer (score 2):

You should check the error log on both Principal and Mirror server.

One common error is that you run your Database Engine Service with a different accounts on your servers, in that case your need to grant connect permissions to the accounts on respective endpoints.

```
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::Endpoint_Mirroring TO [Mydomain\username4service];
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i even tried giving the permission on EndPoints but even after i am getting the below Error:Database Mirroring login attempt failed with error: 'Connection handshake failed. There is no compatible encryption algorithm. State 22.'.  [CLIENT: IP Adress] and if i see my Mirror databse it shows as Mirror,Disconnected/In recovery

Comment: Have you looked at the Encryption algorithm on both servers, they should be the same.
Run:
`Select * sys.dm_db_mirroring_connections`

Comment: Mirroring works fine now after changing End points properly,Need to understand one thing that mirroring will restore data to secondary if there is change in Primary r will it take copy and restore with out checking the data changes in Primary,i mean if there is no change in primary server then it will copy the data to secodary or not?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx        
Check out the overview.